# How do I fill a structure with other object? (like boolean modifier)

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to get a structure which is filled with lattices in insole shape.

I used boolean modifier.
I tried various ways but all didn't work.
One of my trials was this. I made the objects' faces all normals facing out and applied "intersection". But only the surfaces of lattice were left on the insole surface.

Is there anybody who can help me?

[image: The above object is an insole and the other is a lattice structure.]

[image]

I found that the function 'intersection' did work. But exactly what I want to make needs one more step, eliminating the surface so the only lattices could be left in the sphere.
[image]

[image]

I finally got I wanted. I used 'boolean modifier - difference'.
I chose the insole object as modified object and selected the lattice layer as target object.
And I got the object below.

Thanks for helping me.

[image]

Comment: Boolean—Intersection should work. Can you elaborate what you mean with "only the surfaces of lattice were left on the insole surface"? Maybe share a better screenshot or the file itself.

Comment: Your mesh should be not manifold. Please share the file so that we can look at it.